openssl TLS 1.3 Handshake Extensions
I am using freeradius and openssl to do EAP-TLS 1.3 Handshake. So far it works fine.
I want to extend the EAP-TLS Certificate Request message with the extension "oid-filter", defined for TLS 1.3.
Assuming that OpenSSL generates the TLS Certificate Request message, how can someone extend this message, to include a TLS extension?
Regards,
Dincer
I tried to read the openssl code and figure out, where the extension can be added. I looked into freeradius, as well. I expected to hinge somewhere into the code and figure out how to add TLS extensions with openssl, but could not succeed.
